# Service are not registered in Eureka Server. Spring boot 3. No error

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, java-17

I'm doing a Spring boot 3 exercise with microservices and registering them or trying to register in Eureka Server but I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing to get them to register.
I have tried all possible properties but it doesn't work.
The project structure is a bit complex.

*Spring-boot 3, Java17*
payment-chain-parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.paymentchain</groupId>
    <artifactId>payment-chain-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>POM parent project for all spring boot projects</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.1</spring-boot.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies> 
          
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>     
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>      
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>business-domain</module>
        <module>infra-domain</module>
    </modules>
    
</project>
```

infra-parent-project pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.paymentchain</groupId>
        <artifactId>payment-chain-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.paymentchain.infra-domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>infra-domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    
    <modules>
        <module>eureka-server</module>
    </modules>
    
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

eureka-server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.paymentchain.infra-domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>infra-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.paymentchain</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-server</name>
    
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

eureka-server-properties

```
################################
# EUREKA SERVER
################################

spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
#eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.85
eureka.client.service-url.defautZone=${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
```

eureka-server-app

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

product-service-app

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

product-service pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.paymentchain.business-domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>business-domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.paymentchain</groupId>
    <artifactId>product</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>product</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

product-service-properties

```
#################################
##Product MS
#################################

##########################
# eureka client config
##########################
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defautZone=${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

spring.application.name=product-service
server.port=8083
server.servlet.context-path=/api

#swagger-ui uri
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger.html
#enable swagger-ui
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to say really. What are the dependencies of the product-service app?

Comment: @spencergibb all dependencies are managed by busines-domain pom but I added pom product.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
busuness-parent pom change the old version of spring cloud dependency version

*<spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>* to *<spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.paymentchain</groupId>
        <artifactId>payment-chain-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.paymentchain.business-domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>business-domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>  
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>   
        <org.lombok.version>1.18.30</org.lombok.version>     
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>customer</module>
        <module>product</module>
        <module>transaction</module>
    </modules>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
           
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- manage all realate to links on REST resources--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>     
        </dependency>              
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${postgres.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
             
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${java-validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <!--<version>${org.lombok.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- mapper beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <!--<version>3.5.11</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>         
    
</project>
```

Thanks